# jquery .each() with $.get()

Tags: jquery, loops

Basically I am trying to check html values based on .home-val-icons
Get those values create a path and output svg code based on the path created

```
 //Loops through each element
 //Gets html contents
 //Creates a path based on location.origin and html contents
 $('.home-nav-icons').each(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var select =  $(this).html();
    var loc = location.origin;
    var findIcon = loc+"/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/assets/icons/svg/"+select+".svg";
    console.log(findIcon);

    //Gets svg based on path,
    //loops through data objects
    $.get(findIcon, function(data, counter) {
      $.each(data, function(counter) {

        var svgData = data[counter];

        $('.home-nav').append(svgData);

      });
      counter++;
    });
});
```

Console Error:

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document.

Comment: Hi what browser are you using?

Comment: can you wrap the whole each with a `(function() { ... code ... }());`

Comment: You are using 2 times the `counter` var.. Bad thing ~

Comment: I'm using chrome, and the counter is working fine. It's outputting correctly, but returning with "1.0nullCSS1Compatapplication/xml" for each

Answer (score 0):

If it's on Chrome, it could be a bug. Maybe you can avoid it with

```
(function(cookie, localStorage) {
    $('.home-nav-icons').each(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var select =  $(this).html();
    var loc = location.origin;
    var findIcon = loc+"/wp-content/themes/Proxy-Engine/assets/icons/svg/"+select+".svg";
    console.log(findIcon);

    $.get(findIcon, function(data, counter) {
      $.each(data, function(counter) {

        var svgData = data[counter];

        $('.home-nav').append(svgData);

      });
      counter++;
    });
}(cookie, localStorage));
```

So the main point is to wrap it with a function wrapper

```
(function(cookie, localStorage) {...code...} (cookie, localStorage));
```

But i guess this i not the place of that error. So you need to use the wrapper in another scope. Maybe try it with the whole code.

Comment: I tried structuring it the way you suggested, but it didn't output anything and return an error stating that no cookie was set.